# SwiftUI - XML parsing & observing

Tags: xml, networking, tcp, swiftui

I’m developing an app that connects to server over TCP (using Network framework), sends commands and receives XML data. At first, I used structs and vars and in `didStartElement`, `foundCharacters` and `didEndElement` funcs, I added new elements to arrays and set up values. What I found out is that it’s very slow. After that I tried `SwiftyXMLParser` and although it uses Apple’s XMLParser, it works very fast.

The problem is that I can’t observe and change the SwiftUI view.

```
struct ConnectView: View {

    @ObservedObject var connector = Connector.shared
    @State var login = ""
    @State var password = ""

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if connector.serverStatus.connected { //<---ok
//            if connector.xml?.server_status["connected"].bool ?? false { // <---not ok
                MainView().transition(.opacity)
            } else {
                TextField("Login", text: $login)
                SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                Button(action: connect) { Text("Connect") }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Connector: ObservableObject {

    private init() {}

    static let shared = Connector()
    @Published var xml: XML.Accessor!
    @Published var serverStatus: ServerStatus = ServerStatus()

    private static var connection: NWConnection?

    private static func receive() {
       connection?.receive(minimumIncompleteLength: 1, maximumLength: 65535) { (data, _, _, error) in

        //…
        shared.serverStatus.connected = Bool(shared.xml["server_status"].attributes["connected"] ?? "false") ?? false
        //…

        }
     }
}

struct ServerStatus {
    var id: Int?
    var connected: Bool = false
    var recover: Bool?
    var serverTimeZone: String?
    var systemVersion: Int?
    var build: Int?
    var status: String?
}
```

Comment: Why not create a computed property `isConnected` in `Connector` that does all this logic?

Comment: Good idea! But if change to this I get an error: Property wrapper cannot be applied to a computed property. @Published var serverStatus: ServerStatus {
        var serverStatus = ServerStatus()
        serverStatus.connected = xml?.server_status["connected"].bool ?? false
        return serverStatus
    }

Comment: I don't think you need @published on this property, since it's derived from other published properties

Comment: Thank you for your help!